# Effecient way to create 2 django objects that link to each other with a ForeignKey?

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, performance

This seems like a simple question, but I feel like I'm missing something.

I have 2 objects: `A`, and `B`. B has a ForeignKey to A called `my_a`, and for various reasons I need to have a ForeignKey on A to B, i.e. `A.the_b_used`. In a view function I want to create an instance of A (`a = A()`), and an instance of B (`b = B()`), and to then link them together. However my objects (a & b) need to have ids before I can link them (right?), so I think you have to do this:

```
a = A()
b = B()
a.save()
b.save()
a.the_b_used = b
b.my_a = a
a.save()
b.save()
```

It looks like I have to do 4 `.save()`'s, i.e. 4 write database operations. Is there a way to do this without having to do as many database opertions? I might be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you shouldn't need to have a foriegn key from a parent object to a child object if there's already a foreign key from the child back to the parent.  A One-to-one correspondence is achieved by making the foreign key column on the child object unique, so that only one child can link to a particular parent.

Supposing you did exactly this with 'A' as the child, having a foreign key column to parent 'B'.  Since the link from `b` back to `a` is implicit from the link from `a` to `b`, you don't need to know `a`'s id for `b` to be complete.

```
a = A()
b = B()
b.save()
```

`b` has an 'id', which we can use with for `a`

```
a.the_b_used = b
a.save()
```

That's all you should need.